# Displaying Java Metrics results in Graphite

Tags: java, jmx, metrics, graphite, codahale-metrics

I have setup a Graphite server and I am trying to print my Java metrics into the graphite UI. Graphite is up and running as I can see its web UI in localhost. I used the below code to redirect my metrics results to graphite console.

```
Graphite graphite = new Graphite(new InetSocketAddress("http://localhost", 80));
    GraphiteReporter reporter = GraphiteReporter.forRegistry(this.metricRegistry)
            .convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .convertDurationsTo(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .filter(MetricFilter.ALL)
            .build(graphite);
    reporter.start(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

But nothing appears on the web UI. What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to specify any additional configuration for graphite? After installing graphite, I didn't add any configurations.Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InetSocketAddress` you've created points to `localhost` on port `80`. Are you running carbon locally on that port? Normally the web interface will be running behind Apache or nginx on port `80` and the `carbon-cache` process (which actually receives the metrics from the `GraphiteReporter`) will run on port `2003`.

In a standard set-up it should just be a case of switch port `80` with `2003` in your `InetSocketAddress` constructor.